# Injecting JavaScript into a Browser Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm trying to inject javascript into a browser login dialog box.

I'm not sure if that's what its called but it looks like this:

[image]

Is this possible and if so, how?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider just how much of a security leak it would be if you could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. There is no API that would enable that.